# SSAS tabular does not refresh automatically

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I'm using SSASs tabular. Connecting to SSMS as data source and for connection to SQL Server I've chosen "use sql server authentication" and for impersonation "service account"

I've set a job in SSMS

```
{
  "refresh": {
    "type": "automatic",
    "objects": [
      {
        "database": "NBI"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Job successes but the data in SSAS is not updated.
Do you have  any idea about this problem reason?

Comment: See if `"type": "full"` helps

Comment: Yes this worked. but the full process doesn't make duplicate records?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "but the full process doesn't make duplicate records?". Are you saying this is creating duplicate records in your SSAS database? or are you saying you don't want it to load all data?

Comment: I mean does it create duplicate records?

Comment: No. But you should test to confirm. Here's the doco but it's not very clear. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tmsl/refresh-command-tmsl?view=asallproducts-allversions I've found `automatic` to be unreliable in the past so I just use `full`